# Determine is key pressed is alphanumeric in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I'm working on an app for `Windows 8`.

I'm trying to determine if a key pressed is alphanumeric.  The `KeyRoutedEventArgs` class doesn't seem to provide any helpers.

Is there something I'm overlooking? What is the best way to determine if the user entered a letter or number?

Comment: Are you looking for `KeyRoutedEventArgs.Key`?

Comment: Be careful with this, Windows Store apps are distributed around the world.  Particularly users in Asia have unusual opinions about what numbers and letters look like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `KeyRoutedEventArgs` contains a `Key` value which is a VirtualKey.

You can simply test if the `Key` is within the codes you want to support from [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example:

```
private void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int keyValue = (int)e.Key;
    if ((keyValue >= 0x30 && keyValue <= 0x39) // numbers
     || (keyValue >= 0x41 && keyValue <= 0x5A) // letters
     || (keyValue >= 0x60 && keyValue <= 0x69)) // numpad
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample to check if a key pressed is well suited for a phone number (digits, spaces, dots and +) :

```
    using Windows.System;
    ...
    bool isDigitKey(VirtualKey keyValue)
    {
        return ((keyValue >= VirtualKey.Number0 && keyValue <= VirtualKey.Number9)||
            (keyValue >= VirtualKey.NumberPad0 && keyValue <= VirtualKey.NumberPad9));
    }
    private void TextBoxTo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Characters for phone numbers (+, ., space, digits) 
            Boolean isCharFiltered = !isDigitKey(e.Key)        && // Digits
                                 (e.Key != VirtualKey.Space)   && // Space
                                 (e.Key != VirtualKey.Add)     && // + on NumPad
                                 ((int)e.Key != 0xbb)          && // + which is not correctly mapped to VirualKey.Add
                                 (e.Key != VirtualKey.Decimal) && // . on NumPad
                                 ((int)e.Key != 0xbe);            // . which is curiously mapped to Shift
        // Unfortunately, we can't filter à, é and è on a french keyboard because these keys are mapped to Number0, Number2 and Number7

       e.Handled = isCharFiltered;
    }
```